# How to convert text separated with '-' to dataframe

Tags: r, text, dataframe, data-conversion

#### Data

I have a text file with data like this:

```
PMID- 26460049
AB  - Psoriasis is an inflammatory skin disease affecting 2–3% of the population.
AID - 201509971 [pii]
AID - 10.1073/pnas.1509971112 [doi]

PMID- 26999594
AB  - Psoriasis is an autoimmune skin disease that is associated with aberrant activity of immune cells and keratinocytes.
AID - PONE-D-15-54115 [pii]
AID - 10.1371/journal.pone.0151913 [doi]
```

There are more fields and records, but the pattern is that there is a variable name, a '-' separator, some text, possibly multiple lines long, then the data value.

#### Desired output

I'd like to create a data frame like this:

```
PMID      AB                AID                    AID
26460049  Psoriasis is...   201509971 [pii]        10.1073/pnas.1509971112 [doi]
26999594  Psoriasis is...   PONE-D-15-54115 [pii]  10.1371/journal.pone.0151913 [doi]
```

Basically a transposition and recognising the '-' separator as being the demarcation between variable name and datavalues.

#### The question

How do I transpose my file and seperate out the variables and datavalues for this data?

Comment: please can you provide your data by using `dput(your_data)`

Comment: It looks like `-` appears as both a column separator and also as part of a character field. If you have a space after the `-` column identifier (i.e. `- `) then @tobiasegli_te's answer will work. It would be shorter to use `read.csv("/dir/data.csv", sep="- ")`, provided that your columns are separated by `- ` and not `-`.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer, I think `read.csv` can only take a single character `sep` argument. I'm also not sure how it would handle the empty line in the data.

Comment: Very true about the missing lines! I'd not been paying too much attention. My comment regarding `-` appearing as a data character is still valid.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer definitely valid, and as you say `sep = "- "` would be great, if only `read.csv` would accept it. I went with `readLines`, followed by `strsplit`, which is probably a lot slower, and certainly more "clunky".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your text-file has the same structure, you could do:

```
txt <- readLines('input.txt')
dat <- data.frame(pmid = sub('PMID- ', '', txt[grep('PMID-',txt)]),
                  ab = sub('AB  - ', '', txt[grep('AB  -',txt)]),
                  pii = sub('AID - ', '', txt[grep('[pii]',txt,fixed=TRUE)]),
                  doi = sub('AID - ', '', txt[grep('[doi]',txt,fixed=TRUE)]))
```

which gives:

```
> dat
      pmid                                                                                                                   ab                   pii                                doi
1 26460049                                          Psoriasis is an inflammatory skin disease affecting 2–3% of the population.       201509971 [pii]      10.1073/pnas.1509971112 [doi]
2 26999594 Psoriasis is an autoimmune skin disease that is associated with aberrant activity of immune cells and keratinocytes. PONE-D-15-54115 [pii] 10.1371/journal.pone.0151913 [doi]
```

Another possible solution using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [splitstackshape](/questions/tagged/splitstackshape) packages:

```
txt <- readLines('input.txt')

library(splitstackshape) # which also loads 'data.table'
DT <- data.table(txt = txt)[txt!='']
DT <- cSplit(DT, 'txt', sep = '- ', 'wide')

dcast(DT[, `:=` (pmid = txt_2[txt_1=='PMID'][cumsum(txt_1=='PMID')], 
                 txt_1 = sprintf('%s%s',txt_1,c('','','1','2')))][txt_1!='PMID'],
      pmid ~ txt_1, value.var = 'txt_2')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the amount, order and names of your columns are consistent in all entries, I would do:

```
data <- readLines("~/Desktop/data.txt")

PMID_ind <- grep("PMID", data)
data_new <- t(sapply(PMID_ind,function(i_PMID){
    entry_tmp <- data[i_PMID:(i_PMID+3)]
    sapply(entry_tmp,function(split_tmp){
        strsplit(split_tmp,"- ")[[1]][2]
    }, USE.NAMES = F)
}))
colnames(data_new) <- c("PMID","AB","AID1","AID2")
data_new
```

Answer (score -1):

I see another answer has popped up, but I'll post this anyway, since I'd already done it. I'm damn-near certain it's not the best way to do it, but it does work:

```
new <- readLines( file )
new <- strsplit( new, split = "- " )

new <- data.frame( type = sapply( new, "[", 1 ),
                   data = sapply( new, "[", 2 ),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

new <- new[ !is.na( new$type ), ]

new$column.number <- c( 1,2,3,4 )

output <- data.frame(
    PMID = new$data[ new$column.number == 1 ],
    AB = new$data[ new$column.number == 2 ],
    AID.1 = new$data[ new$column.number == 3 ],
    AID.2 = new$data[ new$column.number == 4 ],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

As per @tobiasegli_te's answer, I'm assuming the number of "columns" is constant, as is the order of those columns as represented in the data. The thing that requires that assumption is the fact that two of your "columns" have the same name, meaning the only (?) way to associate them both correctly is to take their position (among the other data) as important. I don't like that, since it's a) difficult to make a generalised solution for, and b) easy to create serious errors with.